# Runtime warning while trying to write equation for line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, runtime-error

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yziC3.png)

This link goes to the picture of the equation i am trying to graph in matplotlib

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x_values = np.arange(1, 10, step=0.1)
y_values = (np.arcsin(np.sqrt(abs(np.sin(x_values) ** (abs(np.cos(x_values)) + abs(np.sin(x_values)) + (2.718281828459045** np.sin(x_values)))))) - x_values)/x_values
```

The code above throws the following error message:

```
ipykernel_launcher.py:4: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.
```

I didn't get to the plotting because this code alone threw an error message
How can i fix this?

Comment: If the answer solved your question, consider accepting the answer and closing the question :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` does not allow fractional powers of negative numbers, since it expects a complex result and you did not define a complex type. You can inspect your power array like this:

```
pow = abs(np.cos(x_values)) + abs(np.sin(x_values)) + (2.718281828459045** np.sin(x_values))
a = np.sin(x_values)
```

and use a workaround like this:

```
a_pow = np.sign(a) * (np.abs(a)) ** (pow)

y_values = (np.arcsin(np.sqrt(abs(a_pow))) - x_values)/x_values
```

But make sure in advance that you are not expecting complex numbers as results!

If you do though, change your array `dtype` to `np.complex`.